# How to extract quoted string for the first place?

Tags: regex, shell, pattern-matching

i have a file which contains these values:-

```
<property name="india" column="delhi" />
<property name="austrelia" column="sydney" />
<property name="uae" column="dubai" />
```

Now i want to extract value inside the first " ".
So result should be :-

```
india
austrelia
uae
```

i am using shell and my regex is "(.*?)" . But it selects both " " value. I want only first one.
Can someone suggest me correct regex for this.

Comment: Maybe we have to clarify some things: in which context are you using regex? (is it really on the shell or maybe php?) what do you want to do with the result and what OS are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
sed -r 's/^[^"]+"([^"]*)".*/\1/' file
```

test with your data:

```
kent$  echo '<property name="india" column="delhi" />
<property name="austrelia" column="sydney" />
<property name="uae" column="dubai" />'|sed -r 's/^[^"]+"([^"]*)".*/\1/'
india
austrelia
uae
```

Comment: Note that on Mac OSX the option for using regex pattern is `-E` instead of `-r`

Comment: @Simon good comment. I have 0 experience of Mac OS. but if you installed gnu sed, the options should be same, right?

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk -F\" '{print $2}' file
```

Btw, probably shell is not ideal tool for parsing XML.